# Configure 2 PIR sensors to activate

Tags: pi-2, sensor

I'm having trouble programming the logic of 2 PIR sensors to print a message in console whenever a user wave their hands on the PIR sensors. I have been able to make 1 of the PIR sensors work which is GPIO 4 but having trouble getting both of them to activate when I wave my hand across the PIR sensors. What I did was duplicate the codes.

.I have managed to successfully attach the PIR sensors to the raspberry pi using GPIO,GND and 5v port and I am reading the sensors from GIPO 4 and 1.
[image]

The program is pretty simple. The Raspberry Pi GPIO pins to allow us to use pin 4 as an input; it can then detect when the PIR module sends power. The pin continually check for any changes, uses a while True loop for this. This is an infinite loop so the program will run continuously unless we stop it manually with Ctrl + C.

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

sensor = 4
sensor2 = 17
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(sensor, GPIO.IN, GPIO.PUD_DOWN)
GPIO.setup(sensor2, GPIO.IN, GPIO.PUD_DOWN)

previous_state = False
current_state = False

previous_state2 = False
current_state2 = False

while True:
    time.sleep(0.1)
    previous_state = current_state
    current_state = GPIO.input(sensor)
    if current_state(TRUE) != previous_state(FALSE):
        new_state = "HIGH" if current_state else "LOW"
        print("GPIO pin %s is %s" % (sensor, new_state))

while True:
    time.sleep(0.1)
    previous_state2 = current_state2
    current_state2 = GPIO.input(sensor2)
    if current_state2(TRUE) != previous_state2(FALSE):
        new_state2 = "HIGH" if current_state2 else "LOW"
        print("GPIO pin %s is %s" % (sensor2, new_state2))
```

I have been able to make 1 PIR works but it's not reading input from GIPO 17. I should receive some message depicted below.

```
GPIO pin 17 is high
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Delete the second `while True:` line.

Currently that line is not reached as the previous `while True:` never completes.